# How to Display Current Function in Eclipse (for Android source code files)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

This is a follow up to [this old post **How to Display Current Function in Eclipse**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514779/how-to-display-current-function-in-eclipse)

The answers in that post work well for local sources, i.e. my own code.
Since then Eclipse ADT installations started to include the Android platform source code.
If you open any of it, directly or through your project's *android.jar* package explorer, **none of those answers work**.

So I repeat the question but for these tricky files:

### I would like to know the name of the current function the cursor is currently inside when browsing Android source code.

Comment: May be if you point your jar to its source file locally and do CTRl+O, it may work..

Comment: @Susie Nope, that's one of the solutions offered in the old post, it does not work. I tried it. I mean, ctrl+o opens the outline popup, but it does not show you which method you are in. Moreover, some methods in those source files do not appear in the outline at all (and they are not annotated in any way, for example `measureVertical()` in `LinearLayout.java`)

Comment: I use mockito jar file and have downloaded and pointed to its source file locally. When I do CTRL+O, it gives me the list of all the methods, with the one the cursor is in highlighted.

Comment: @Susie well, it does not work for the Andriod source files included in the Eclipse installation, attached to the Android jar file.